# Objective C: Part of UITableView hidden by Tab bar controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

Hi I have a Uitableview added to a Uiviewcontroller as seen in the code below. The controller is part of a UITabbarcontroller.

The problem here is that the tab bar (at bottom of screen) overlaps with the table view. Is there any way to shorten the table height so that it is not partially hidden by the tab bar?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame] autorelease];

    self.feedTableView = [[UITableView alloc]init];

    self.feedTableView.frame = self.view.bounds;

    self.feedTableView.delegate = self;
    self.feedTableView.dataSource = self;

    [self.view addSubview: self.feedTableView];

    [self getData];

    [self.feedTableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems here:

- You set self.view in viewDidLoad (it should already have been set in loadView).
- You set the view frame to applicationframe, but your view does not take up the whole applicationframe (the tab bar controller's view probably does that).

When you have a tabbarcontroller and set viewcontrollers inside it, the tabbarcontroller sets up all the viewcontrollers (tells them when to load and what size to have and when to show). You should never need to set the view's frames in this case. So removing that first line after `[super viewDidLoad];` should fix your problem.

Comment: Hey @vakio. I am confused. How does removing [super viewDidLoad] help ?

Comment: @Legolas, it's the first line AFTER [super viewDidLoad].

Comment: I removed the line to set self.view. Unfortunately the problem persists. Do I have to change the way I set the tableview frame?

Comment: Hmm. You shouldn't have to. I can't figure it out.. unless the viewcontroller isn't inside the tabbarcontroller (like if you did something crazy like `tabbarController.view addSubview:viewController.view` or if `getData` sets the frame again).

Though I recommend you find out what is causing this instead, a quick and dirty is to just subtract the tabbar's height (49) from the height of the tableView's frame.

Comment: I realised my issue was with fact that I didnt add the top navigation bar and bottom tab bar in my nib file (as part of the Simulated Metrics" section. I wasn't aware that the simulated metrics will impact the frame size. I added the top nav bar and bottom tab bar and my issue of overlapping is resolved. Thanks for your help!